# fatal exception in android studio after compiling

Tags: android-fragments

Hi am beginner in android studio while performing fragment example in android studio i got this error while running of my project while clicking a button in my app it shows a message "Unfortunately your app has stopped".I have checked in my log it shows the following i don't know how to solve it.???

> com.example.xxx.xxx E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.xxx.xxx.MenuFragment cannot be cast to com.example.xxxx.xxxx.TextFragment
>               at com.example.xxxx.xxx.MenuFragment.onListItemClick(MenuFragment.java:28)
>               at android.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:160)
>               at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
>               at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1584)
>               at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3399)
>               at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:4653)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

thank you in advance

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.xxx.xxx.MenuFragment cannot be cast to com.example.xxxx.xxxx.TextFragment. You casting different classes. Check your source code at MenuFragment.java line number 28.

Comment: You should post your code snippet and relevant classes also for more help.